# Select how much data the pd.mean() displays?

Tags: python, pandas

When returning the `pd.mean()`, how to show only specific information?

**Example**

Now it gives this:

```
new_df = pd.read_excel('example.xls', usecols = ['weight'] )
print('avg value for column weight is here: '+ str(data.mean()))
```

Result

```
avg value for column weight is here: weight 2311.000000 dtype: float64
```

it should return:

```
avg value for column weight is here: 2311.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For avoid one value `Series` select column `weight`. If use [`Series.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html) - call function for one column get scalar output:

```
print('avg value for column weight is here: '+ str(data['weight'].mean()))
```

Or use `f-strings` for same ouput:

```
print(f'avg value for column weight is here: {data["weight"].mean()}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of data, which returns mean values for the dataframe,using `df['weight']`
or
`df.weight`,

will return the mean of just the dataframe column. df['weight'] is basically slicing the  dataframe to return a series, which means you're specifying exactly what you want the mean of, so the column name value isn't returned.

fstrings are a useful way to change this if there was no other way to alter the input, as they force an output into a string value. This would have to be coupled with using [] slice notation to return only the specific characters from the string that you want displayed

you literally just add an f"" around your input and {} around any field that needs replacing with a string

```
print(f"avg value for column weight is here: {data["weight"].mean()}")
```